# genfromtxt: how to disable caching

Tags: python, numpy

I have confirmed that the *genfromtxt* function (and those derived from it) silently cache the remote file they are processing in a local directory and use the local copy in subsequent invocations without checking if it has changed.
By looking in to the source file [*npyio.py*](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1180) it seems this happens because the [DataSource](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/_datasource.py#L154) object that  handles the request is created without passing the relevant parameter.
It is of course easy to modify the library sources to disable caching but then I would have to repeat that after every upgrade.
Is there any other solution? (apart from deleting the cache directory every time)

Comment: To disable caching one has to modify line 1360 in the linked npyio.py to read:  `  fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU',None)) `

Comment: Does opening the file yourself,and passing that object to `genfromtxt` help?

Comment: Yes it seems to work, and combined with the suggestion below probably answers the question. The cost being that some functionality of the original function is duplicated and one must study and understand _genfromtxt_ source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying the library source, I realized that the required behaviour could be achieved by modifying the defaults of a small helper function called *open* in numpy's *datasource* module. As suggested above, this is possible without modifying the library source. Here is the code I came with:

```
import numpy
from numpy.lib._datasource import DataSource
#def open(path, mode='r', destpath=os.curdir):
def openm(path, mode='r', destpath=None):
  ds = DataSource(destpath)
  return ds.open(path, mode)
numpy.lib._datasource.open=openm
```

which has to be included before calling *genfromtxt* or the functions derived from it.
But my study has further revealed that these functions are quite slow, and that in Windows disabling caching produces a warning - this is not due to the redefinition above, it appears to be related to the way the *mktemp* function is implemented in Windows. Furthermore the cached file and the associated temporary directories are not deleted.

This seems to be related to the fact that the datasource handling the request is coming out of scope (and therefore deleted) before the file is read and closed. When the datasource's destructor is executed it tries to remove the datasource's directory, the operation fails as the filehandle is still open, so the warning. I am thinking to move the datasource instantiation in the genfromtxt function.
**I confirm that moving the datasource instantiation in the genfromtxt function works properly under Windows and Linux**, therefore I consider this the proper solution.

**I have come to the conclusion that the most clean approach is to modify the *numpy* library and add cache parameter to *genfromtxt***

Here are the necessary modifications to npyio.py, just a couple of lines have to be modified.
The genfromtxt function prototype changes from

```
def genfromtxt(fname, dtype=float, comments='#', delimiter=None,
           skiprows=0, skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None,
           missing='', missing_values=None, filling_values=None,
           usecols=None, names=None,
           excludelist=None, deletechars=None, replace_space='_',
           autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt="f%i",
           unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True):
```

to (a new cache parameter is added)

```
def genfromtxt(fname, dtype=float, comments='#', delimiter=None,
           skiprows=0, skip_header=0, skip_footer=0, converters=None,
           missing='', missing_values=None, filling_values=None,
           usecols=None, names=None,
           excludelist=None, deletechars=None, replace_space='_',
           autostrip=False, case_sensitive=True, defaultfmt="f%i",
           unpack=None, usemask=False, loose=True, invalid_raise=True,cache=True):
```

and the lines opening the file/url change from

```
if isinstance(fname, basestring):
    fhd = iter(np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rbU')
    own_fhd = True
```

to

```
if isinstance(fname, basestring):
    ds=DataSource('.' if cache==True else None)
    fhd = iter(ds.open(fname, 'rbU'if cache==True else 'rbUD'))
    own_fhd = True
```

'D' is a Windows specific flag to open (harmless in Linux) that marks a file temporary, automatically deleted when the file handle is closed.

**The Wrapper Function Version**

```
def mgenfromtxt(fname,cache=True,**karg):
    if cache==False and isinstance(fname, basestring) and numpy.DataSource()._isurl(fname):
       ds=numpy.DataSource(None)
       fhd = iter(ds.open(fname,'rbUD'))
       l1=numpy.genfromtxt(fhd,**karg)
       fhd.close()
       del ds
       return l1
    else:
       return(numpy.genfromtxt(fname,**karg))
```

Comment: I would like to thank the people who responded to my question [Python file open function modes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502329/python-file-open-function-modes) and clarified mode character 'D'

Comment: If one prefers not to modify the library, one could instantiate the datasource and open the url in the calling function, passing the file handle to genfromtext as suggested above by @hpaulj.

Comment: One could also implement this functionality in a wrapper function (possibly with injection) as suggested by @ami-tavory in his answer. I thank them both.

Answer (score 3):

I think this question is actually composed of two parts:

1. What to do if a library's functionality does not exactly match the required behavior?
2. How to handle `genfromtxt`'s caching behavior in particular?

Regarding 1., wrapping (possibly with injection) is a more resilient way than patching the library (except if the patch is done upstream, in the library's repo).

So wrapping `genfromtxt` could be done like:

```
def patched_gen_from_text(*args, **kwargs):
    # Do something regarding caching
    return numpy.genfromtxt(*args, **kwargs)
```

you could even inject this as numpy.genfromtext without modifying the sources (not that I would recommend this):

```
import numpy 

numpy.genfromtxt = patched_gen_from_text
```

Regarding 2. it really depends on the access you have to the remote filesystem (e.g., can you run there a proces? can you mount it?), and the tradeoff between speed and certainty required.

E.g., at one extreme, your patched version could unconditionally erase the local file (certain but slow). Alternatively, you might be able to request the remote file's update time and length, and see how they correspond to the local file. At the other extreme, you might be able to run an md5 check on RPC at the other computer.

You might want to check [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) for different comparison options, as well as a possible actual building block for some of the cases.

Comment: Clarified what I was trying to say.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the insights of part 1. Regarding part 2, I will probably have to implement an unconditional delete of the temporary file on return from genfromtxt wrapping it as you suggest.